# How to remove invisible border from Windows 10 window

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I would like to know how to remove the invisible border of a Windows 10 window. The update from windows 7 to windows 10 of my application provoked that.

I am using c++ MFC.

---

Here's an image of the application with Windows 7 : 
[image]

---

With Windows 10 :

### [image]

I've tried with the windows message WM_NCCALCSIZE, it removed the space between the two dialogs, but it removed the border and the title bar :

### [image]

I can't play with the position of the window.

---

Is there anyway to get the border and the title back using WM_NCCALCSIZE or using a different window style ?

Thx :)

Or is there anyway to turn the invisible border visible and with a color ? Thx.

Comment: There is a way to do it with [DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx) but you end up redrawing the whole non-client area. It usually ends up looking odd and unreliable. I think you you just want to line up the windows, you could offset the window position a little to the left in that case.

Comment: Change the window style to exclude WS_THICKFRAME.

Comment: @Adrian Probably not resizeable if you do that, but maybe the OP doesn't care (or can do something himself with WM_NCHITTEST).

Comment: I don't care if the window is not resizeable and I've tried removing WS_THICKFRAME, but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: I'm using the ModifyStyle() function to remove WS_THICKFRAME in OnNcCalcSize(), but as I mentioned before, it does not work. Someone has an idea why ? Thx.